# Eclipse & JAR Hell

Tags: java, eclipse, build

**EDIT:** I appreciate the suggestions for Ivy or Maven, but this is just not an option for me at this time. I do not have the authority to use those tools. I am simply looking for a way to get my referenced .classpath JARs into a folder inside my project.

I have created a project that uses about 50 external JAR files that I referenced from other projects inside the same workspace.

Thus, my project's directory strucure looks like:

```
MyProject
    src/
    test/
    Referenced Libraries/
        ... 50+ JARs
    lib/
```

My project compiles and runs beautifully inside Eclipse. But now I need to add a buildscript so other developers can pull the project down from SVN and run it standalone. To do that, I'd like to place all the JARs that are currently in Eclipse's in-house directory `Referenced Libraries` and copy them into my project's `lib` directory which I will JAR-up with the final distribution.

I'm in Package Explorer, and have tried to just copy + paste the files from `Referenced Libraries` to `lib/` and no dice. I get the following Eclipse error:

```
Cannot paste the clipboard contents into the selected elements.
```

Anybody have any idea how I can force this copy operation to work? If I right-click any JAR inside `Referenced Libraries` I see an Eclipse option called **Migrate JAR file**, but I'm afraid that would *cut*-n-paste the JARs from their current location to the new `lib/` directory. This isn't feasible because there are many other projects that need these JAR files exactly where they are.

Thanks for any insight here!

Comment: The 'Package Explorer' view in Eclipse is not a true file system view. Try the Navigator view instead if you want to copy files. Plus, the 'Referenced Libraries' view is just a logical view of those libraries that are on your build path - it's not a real file system directory. If I were you, and your project allows it, I would have a look at Maven to manage your dependencies and the packaging of your application.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a dependency management tool such as Maven or Apache Ivy.

Comment: OK now we're getting somewhere! So I switched to Navigator View and saw a file named .classpath which shows all my JARs on the classpath. So the next logical question is: how do I get all those JARs  referenced in .classpath to be copied into my lib/ directory at buildtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't find another way to go but to copy yourself the jars into your lib folder, add the references to your lib files (not to external jars on your machine) and upload it to SVN.

EDIT to clarify:

1. Remove all references from your build path. Now you can't compile the project.
2. Copy every jar file you need to your project's lib folder.
3. Go again to build path and add the references to your jars (the ones on lib) one by one. Use the button that says "Add JARs...", not the one that says "external JARs".
4. Compile, and if everything is fine,
5. Upload the whole project to SVN.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/)? It's an exceptional tool for situations like this. For file operations it's best to use Navigator view.

Comment: Yes, please DO consider switching to Maven.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this is not an answer to the question and platform-level decisions are outside the scope of my control. I am stuck with Ant/Eclipse. Thanks for the recommendation though!

Comment: Agree. And i think it is already integrated in the new Eclipse Indigo.