# cannot paste clipboard contents into selected elements Eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

I'm trying to create a simple login form using servlets connected to database. But I got this error:

> No JDBC driver found

I had added `mysql-connector` as external JAR file. After searching for solution on stackoverlow, it was suggested instead of adding it as external JAR file, copy paste it into `WEB-INF/LIB` folder. But whenever I try that, it gives me error:

> Cannot paste clipboard contents into selected elements

How can I resolve this?

EDIT 1: Eclipse not allowing me to drag-drop either

Comment: You could try using a file-browser of your choice (or either cp or mv if you're on a linux CLI)

Comment: instead of copy paste try to drag file and place it in web-inf/lib folder

Comment: Open "Navigator" and then try pasting again.

Comment: @Dragondraikk could you please post your comment as answer so I can accept it.... It worked.. :)

Comment: @user270386 It's not really an answer though, I just told you to move files with a file-browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix it in that case, extract the file(s) from the archive first(.rar,.tar,.zip), then c-and-paste the file into Eclipse. Works for me under Package Explorer, too.

OR  Go for

```
project->clean
```

just go through that 
[Eclipse & JAR Hell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322016/eclipse-jar-hell)

May be that Help you out !!

Comment: It is already extracted. And I have checked that post yesterday itself :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of copy paste try to drag file and place it in web-inf/lib folder

Answer (score 0):

please Be sure that the file is not from a zip folder.
If it is from zip folder extract it , then copy paste the file.

Answer (score 0):

- download winrar-x64 /winrar-x32
- install winrar
- now unzip ur files
- copy paste in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

### Best Solution:

Yes i try to start learning JDBC and had to face this issue.

I read the stackoverflow posts but nothing seems to be solving my issue.

Then i did one thing

1.Right click the project

2.Go to properties

3.java Build path

4.libraries

5.Add external Jars

6.Add the jar file

7.hit ok to save

8.Then copy and paste same jar file into the project that you have done before

9.Success!you won't see any error prompt

I am happy now and i hope that you too when you follow this procedure